# Cancel insert Command Operation if connection timeouts MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, c#-4.0

I would Like to know if it's possible to cancel an insert operation if the connection times out. The reason I am asking this question is because I was uploading a blob(2-5 megabytes) one time but my internet connection was slow so the connection timed out before the upload was completed. This isn't a really big issue for me as I can simply increase the connection timeout next time and try again. My issue however is that when I check my table I noticed that MySQL still recorded the insertion of a new entry which I don't want.

Here is the code I am  using;

```
        Connection.Open();
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\linuxuser\Pictures\Newfolder\36.jpg");
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `FileStorage` SET `File` = @image", Connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", MySqlDbType.Blob).Value = bytes;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 180;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        Connection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("SUccess");
```

NOTE: The Table has an Auto-Incremented Primary Key Field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Transactions to insert new entry in your table [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html).

```
   MySqlTransaction trans;
   trans = connection.BeginTransaction();
   // Your Code 
   try
    {
       //By default, MySQL runs with autocommit mode enabled.
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", MySqlDbType.Blob).Value = bytes;            
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `FileStorage` SET `File` = "+@image"";
        cmd.executeNonQuery();      
        trans.Commit();
    }
     catch(Exception e)
      {
         try
         {
            myTrans.Rollback();
         }
       catch (MySqlException ex)
          {
            if (trans.Connection != null)
            {
              //("An exception of type " + ex.GetType() +" was encountered while attempting to roll back the transaction.");
            }
           }
        }
```